# Rspec stubbing not working with before_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stubbing

Here is my test:

```
it "should have shortened links that when clicked, redirect me back to the
      original url" do
      allow_any_instance_of(Link).to receive(:shorten_url).and_return("bit.ly-remix/11111111")
      link = build(:link, orig_url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=balut+egg&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=678&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=CngVVanlMIG5ogSap4GQDQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=qnYT21R-r5VDRM%253A%3BIbuD8fXhkqTEDM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bizarrefood.com%252Fblog%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F08%252Fbalut.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bizarrefood.com%252Fblog%252Ffertilized-duck-embryo-balut%252F%3B295%3B300")

     visit root_path
     click_link link.short_url

     expect(page).to have_content("wikipedia")
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :shorten_url

  def self.sort_by_clicks
    order(clicks: :desc, created_at: :desc).all
  end

  def shorten_url
    self.short_url = (Figaro.env.base_url || "localhost:3000/") + SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6)
  end
end
```

The problem is that link.short_url does not return me back the stubbed url that I want in my database. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you use FactoryGirl, then build(:link) only creates new instance, but does not save it to database.

So you should, probably use

```
link = create(:link, orig_url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=balut+egg&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=678&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=CngVVanlMIG5ogSap4GQDQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=qnYT21R-r5VDRM%253A%3BIbuD8fXhkqTEDM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bizarrefood.com%252Fblog%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F08%252Fbalut.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bizarrefood.com%252Fblog%252Ffertilized-duck-embryo-balut%252F%3B295%3B300")
```

In your tests, to force callback trigger.

Or, from the other side you can stub self.short_url method at Link model.